# HC-SR04 Ultrasonic Rangefinder readings are off by a large margin

Tags: sensor, python-3

I'm making a robot that should avoid obstacles and im using a HC-SR04 to measure distances. My problem is that my readings are off by a large margin. when there is no obstacle in the way I get a constant measure around 100 cm, but when I place an object in front of the reader suddenly it goes up to about 2000 cm. I've tried using the gpiozero library aswell, but same thing keeps happening. Is the reader damaged or what can I try?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import signal
import sys

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pinTrigger = 12
pinEcho = 16

def close(signal, frame):

    GPIO.cleanup() 
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)


GPIO.setup(pinTrigger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinEcho, GPIO.IN)

while True:

    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, False)

    startTime = time.time()
    stopTime = time.time()

    while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        startTime = time.time()

    while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        stopTime = time.time()


    TimeElapsed = stopTime - startTime
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    print ("Distance: %.1f cm" % distance)
    time.sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please try http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_sonar_trigger_echo_py and report the results.  You will need to edit the file at the end, change `sonar = sonar_trigger_echo.ranger(pi, 23, 18)` to `sonar = sonar_trigger_echo.ranger(pi, 12, 16)`.  Run `sudo pigpiod` before running the script.

Comment: Im gettting values like this:

(651 9164)

(652 6555)

(653 6547)

(654 6370)

(655 5)

(656 8914)

(657 8860)

(658 8837)



it seems to understand though when an object is very close, then I get the reading "5" or "10" @joan

Comment: The first number is the reading count, the second number is the echo round trip time in microseconds.  Use (micros/1000000)*17015 to get distance in centimetres.  Do the figures seem to follow as you slowly move an object to and fro?

Comment: n1 = sonar.read()
n2 = n1 / 1000000
n3 = n2 * 17015

print(n3)


constantly shows around 100cm, and when an object is around 10cm away it starts to read 0.08 cm @joan

Comment: There will be a minimum distance, perhaps it is 10 cms.  Are you saying the readings don't vary as you move the object to and fro?

Comment: Anything further away than 10 cm, will just show values between 90cm-110cm
@joan

Comment: Then something is wrong.  Are you powering the sonar ranger from 5V?  Clear photos of of your setup please.

Comment: Im powering the sensor with 6 AA batteries, im using a 1k ohm resistor and a 2k ohm resistor. The batteries power 2 DC motors aswell. The pi is powered by a regular powerbank.
https://imgur.com/a/cl1ERvv
@joan

Comment: Try powering the sonar from the Pi's 5V supply.  Potentially 9V from the batteries may be too much.  Also make sure the sonar ranger ground is connected to a Pi ground.

Comment: If the echo and trigger are wired backwards, it will still work but you will get strange readings.